# rails display one to many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, one-to-many

product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :case_products, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :cases, through: :case_products
end
```

This one works but it gives me the chart for each @users.cases.product
I want one chart for them all
in user show

```
<% @user.cases.each do |t| %>
  <%= pie_chart t.products.group(:name).count %>
<% end %>
```

how can I do something like

```
 <%= pie_chart @user.cases.products.group(:name).count %>
```

Comment: Add relations to the User class. Something like User `has_many :products, through: :cases` and then you can do `@user.products.group(:name).count`.